# App that only fails the first time it is run on a device (also in iphone simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iOS app that only fails the first time it is run on a device (also in the simulator) when it tries to access the calendar to create an event. If I uninstall and reinstall the app, or remove the files from ~/Library/Application Support/iphone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications, I can´t reproduce the error.

Thank you.

Comment: How does it fail? Is there an exception? If so, what is it? You say you can't reproduce it—what have you tried?

Comment: The mistake only happened the first time, but don't close the application. The problem is that I can't reproduce, and even if you uninstall and reinstall the application on the device or in the simulator, I can't repeat the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use IPCU(iPhone Configuration Utility). Using this you can see the client logs, server logs and OS logs. This is very useful to trace. You mentioned only happening in very first time in device and simulator as well. So what my suggestion is install the new simulator (Another version) and test it again. Seems to be you are running the app in 7.0.3 version of device. Try to run the application in lower version devices or simulators. I hope this helps you.